# Can a superclass store its subclasses in a list statically?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I have a super class, SuperClass. I want a JList displaying every subclass of SuperClass. Not how many subclasses of SuperClass were instantiated, but how many subclasses I have actually defined in my program. The point is that it should be easy to add new subclasses without changing code anywhere else.

I'm hoping that my SuperClass can define a static map that would increase for every subclass I define (not instantiate). Now by clicking on the items of the JList the appropriate subclasses should be instantiated.

I will try to show what I want to do:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    protected static ArrayList<?extends SuperClass> subclasses = new ArrayList<>();
}
class SubClassOne extends SuperClass {
    static {
        subclasses.add(this)
    }
}
```

Now I realize there are lots of problems with above code, but I hope it clarifies what I want. I'm entirely clueless how I should proceed with regards to instantiating my subclasses from the JList.

Please specify if I can give any more information that could be of help.

Comment: Sure, you can use the getClass() method or the .class variable, but I'm not sure why you think you need to do this. You can also use javadoc to automatically generate this list outside of your code.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I'll need a lot more help :/ If you understand the problem and know the solution, I really would appreciate a detailed answer. Right now I can only ask: What can I use getClass and .class for?

Comment: Like other answers have said, you can use it to populate a data structure that contains these classes. You could also use javadoc to generate this list.

Comment: Note that all answers track the subclasses that have been *loaded* in the VM, they exclude the ones that you have defined and are available in the `classpath` (or the `ClassLoaders`) but have not been loaded yet. That problem is lot more difficult to solve because it is essentially impossible to know what classes may be available for loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As demonstrated by the other answers, it is not suited for *inheritance*. Rather look at the *factory* pattern: some factory class that holds (a map of) classes, and it can instantiate objects of one of those classes.

There are some standard mechanisms in Java.

1. You could make your own annotation; use **annotation processing**

   ```
   @Factored
   public class A {
   }

   @Factored
   public class B {
   }
   ```

   This is a large coding overhead.
2. You could use the java **service provider interface**

   This SPI is used for detecting XML parsers and such, where jars on the class path have a file under MANIFEST with a text file with a file name the interface class path.
   In it one or more implementation classes may be listed. These implementations can then be listed.

   This is a declarative approach, so lacks the desired automatism.
3. Make an **enum of factories**

   Suitable only for a limited close-world set of classes, also giving strong dependencies.

   ```
   public enum Factory<T> {
       F_A(A.class),
       F_B(B.class);

       private static final Set<Class<T>> klasses = new HashSet<>();
       static {
           for (Factory f : values()) {
               klasses.add(f.klass);
           }
       }

       public final Class<T> klass;

       private Factory(Class<T> klass) {
           this.klass = klass;
       }

       //public <S extends T> S instantiate(Class<S> kl) {
       public T instantiate() {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static initializer block in your subclasses:

```
public class MySubclass extends MySuperclass {

    static {
        MySuperclass.register(MySubclass.class);
    }
}
```

then in your superclass you can have a `register` method like this:

```
protected static void reigster(Class<?> clazz) {
    subclasses.add(clazz);
}
```

Then when you want to instantiate a class:

```
MySuperclass subclassInstance = subclasses.get(someIndex).newInstance();
```

Note that this only works if you actually load those classes. For dynamic class loading you might have to implement your own `ClassLoader` or use some dynamic OSGi framework like the Apache Felix.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    protected static ArrayList<Class<? extends SuperClass>> subclasses = new ArrayList<>();
}
class SubClassOne extends SuperClass {
    static {
        subclasses.add(SubClassOne.class);
    }
 }
```

**Approach 2**

Scan entire classpath (using reflection), iterate for each class and check if the class inherits from your superclass.
You could look into [Reflections library](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/). I'd do it for you in an easy way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the list will be empty until the subclass is actually loaded and initialized by the JVM. If no code ever causes the initialization of a subclass, the subclass won't appear in the list.

Comment: @JBNizet Is it possible to fill the SuperClass.subclasses without instanciating any subclasses? Is there another way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: @user2651804 Apart from scanning the jars in the classpath somehow to detect all the subclasses, no, I don't see how it would be possible. This sounds like an XY problem to me. You should explain what you want to achieve, at a higher level, to see if you couldn't use a better design. Why do you need this to be dynamic?

Comment: @TanmayPatil I'm entirely unable to understand your second approach. I've never attempted anything like it or heard of it. If you'd take the time I'd appreciate your help :-)

Comment: @JBNizet I need to by dynamic only because I refused to believe I couldn't. I'm only coding to learn, so I'm very concerned with design: Adding a new line to my JList everytime I add a subclass to SuperClass just raised a red flag for me.

Comment: @user2651804: storing Class instances in a JList is really dubious. You should store objects instead. Maybe what you need is an enum. But without knowing the end goal, it's hard to suggest a good design.

Comment: @JBNizet Probably shouldn't turn this post into a discussions' forum. Doesn't SO offer some way for users to chat?
It's frustrating me that every time I ask a question the one thing I'm always told is: "Why would you do something that stupid?"
Thanks for the link Tanmay :-)

Comment: That should be a hint: you should describe why you're doing things, and not simply ask how to do something. Especially when the question is a design question.

Comment: @JBNizet I thought long and hard on how to turn my design problems into an SO question. I think I failed pretty bad, but I hope you can be of help with concrete information on what I'm trying to do:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489615/how-should-i-be-using-subclasses-in-java

Comment: Updated link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44698/making-additional-subclasses-at-any-time-should-be-as-painless-as-possible